# How can I configure the color of 'ls' directory under zsh

Tags: zsh

I am using 'zsh'. In some directory, when I do `ls --color=tty`. I see some directories have
'blue text' with 'green background', which makes them hard to read.

Can you please tell me how to configure this?

Comment: This is unrelated to zsh. It depends however on which `ls` implementation you are using. Do a _man ls_.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Assuming you are using GNU `ls`, you can [specify the colors with the environment variable LS_COLORS](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dircolors-invocation.html#dircolors-invocation) (note that this is a GNU `ls` feature and not specific to zsh).

GNU Coreutils has a program called `dircolors` to help you convert an easy to edit configuration file into a proper (complicated) LS_COLORS variable. See `man dircolors` for the command, and `man dir_colors` for the configuration file syntax.

You can

1. use `dircolors --print-database >! dircolors.default` to save the defaults (it contains some explanation text) and then modify it.
2. Google for fancy pre-configured dircolors files (such as this https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized (I've got no relation to this)).

Once done, you'll need `dircolors` to turn that into a proper LS_COLORS. Note that `dircolors` outputs in bash and csh formats, for `zsh` you should use the `bash`-formatted output.

PS: Use `ls --color=auto` instead of `ls --color=tty`.

Comment: this is not true for custom colors. `LS_COLOR` does not work by default on zsh for some reason. See the numerous other posts complaining about this: 1) https://superuser.com/questions/700406/zsh-not-recognizing-ls-colors 2) https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/5349

Comment: You're redirecting with `>!`. What does the exclamation point do?

Comment: `>!` "Same as >, except that the file is truncated to zero length if it exists, regardless of CLOBBER. " https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Redirection.html

Answer (score 21):

The following works for me in zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)).

These lines in my .zshrc without any additional incantations configure the colours for ls:

```bsh
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExGxBxDxCxEgEdxbxgxcxd
alias ll="ls -alG"
```

For the configuration options you can use in LSCOLORS you can simply run `man ls` and find the section for LSCOLORS. CLICOLOR is explained there as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the blue color and restore the default white color, just uncomment the line "DISABLE_LS_COLORS =" true "in your .zshrc file