# Zsh not recognizing ls colors

Tags: terminal, zsh

I just was introduced to Zsh and so far I am really liking the customizability.

I use the following line to set up colors in .zshrc:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ''
```

This gives me these colors:

[image]

However when I use `ls` (I have aliased it to `ls -G`) I get the following colors:

[image]

Is there a way to make the Zsh `list-colors` the same as `ls`?

**EDIT:**

I have also tried setting the colors to the ls defaults from `man ls` without success (the colors still appear the same as the first image):

```
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors 'exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The *proper* way of configuring colors with GNU ls is using `LS_COLORS` (see https://superuser.com/a/530467/175441). Now assuming you have `LS_COLORS` set, you should now use

```
# Zsh to use the same colors as ls
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
```

BTW, the above works. Search for `list-colors` in the Zsh manual (i.e. `man zshall`). If you cannot get this to work, try running this (short `LS_COLORS` for convenience...):

```
LS_COLORS='no=00;37:fi=00:di=00;33:ln=04;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:bd=40;33;01:'
export LS_COLORS
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
```

Comment: Zsh doesn't like those colors. You get the same output as `zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ''`

Comment: Did you check whether `LS_COLORS` is empty? Either way you are doing something wrong. The command I described is in the Zsh manual.

Comment: @cabellicar123 make sure your `TERM` is included among valid terminals in the dircolors configuration file, i.e. include yours if it is not there. Otherwise, dircolors generates an empty value.

Comment: To clarify, to set ls colors in ZSH you define LSCOLORS, which uses the 'exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad' format. GNU uses LS_COLORS which uses the  'no=00;37:fi=00:di=00;33:ln=04;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:bd=40;33;01:' format, as does autocomplete. If you want them to match, use http://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/ to generate both

Comment: I tried the above but it doesn't seem to obey the ones I am putting, it seems to be using the default ones. I used a different variable:
`
LS_COLORS='di=1:fi=96:*.m=31:*.py=32:*.txt=36:*.out=35'
export LS_COLORS
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
`

Comment: Why is this the proper way? The @carloabelli answer in conjunction with the notif about the CLICOLOR variable works just fine for me on MacOS

Comment: Should we define it inside `.zshrc`?

Comment: I put `zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS} `  in `~/.zshrc`, and worked, but **only after I source'd the file twice** ...

Comment: My god. Thank you @Francisco I was tearing out my hair. Was missing the third line, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 15):

In my case, I also had to

```
export CLICOLOR=1
```

to get ls to colorize its output, as documented in `man ls`.

Comment: This may be necessary on BSD / MacOS systems, but with GNU ls implementations, `--color` is the only consideration.

Answer (score 12):

Default `ls` parameter `--color=auto` does colorize the output in zsh as well. Thus, there will be no need to use `zstyle` or `CLICOLOR`/`LS_COLORS`.

Simply adjust the following alias for your needs and append it to the `.zshrc` file.

```
alias ls="ls --color=auto"
```

Answer (score 4):

Turns out `zsh` doesn't like the way `ls` stores its colors. You have to convert the colors into something `zsh` understands.

```
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors 'di=34:ln=35:so=32:pi=33:ex=31:bd=46;34:cd=43;34:su=41;30:sg=46;30:tw=42;30:ow=43;30'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on MacOS the BSD version of ls does not use LS_COLORS, but you can use the GNU version of ls instead:

```
brew install coreutils
alias ls="gls --color"
```

From: https://github.com/sharkdp/vivid#on-macos